# LinkedIn Posting API verification

Tags: linkedin-api, verification, formal-verification

we are a young startup and would like to program a social media channel manager.
For this we need the LinkedIn Posting API.

We have already applied for multiple verifications with LinkedIn.

Unfortunately, however, these verifications have always been rejected for various reasons. Queries were not answered.

The last points we need to fulfill for approval are

*1. To showcase the Page Management use case- We like to see in your application what member information who has interacted with your post. For instance, when a User clicks on some reaction or comments on your post,

2. what member details are shown to your Page admin in your App?
   Once you publish post from your application show us how it will reflect on LinkedIn company page with comments or reactions.
3. .Profile Management -An app user reviewing a member’s comment on a company page post or profile post; or What personal data fields from the commenting member’s LinkedIn profile can be viewed by the app user.
4. Page Analytics-Demonstrate how you will track post performances.
5. Employee Advocacy -Please demonstrate in video.*

Unfortunately, we cannot fulfill the second point, for example, because we do not yet have access to the API. and What does the fifth point mean?

We would appreciate support from the community. We would also like to bring in a consultant for our project who already has experience with the verification process.

Many thanks in advance.

We have already created several detailed videos and sent them to LinkedIn.
We have sent in queries via email and contacted LinkedIn support.